# linkedin-j getting network updates

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Hie

I am using linkedin-j apis and trying to search the available public feeds for a set of keywords say oracle and google. That is, i should get all the feeds which mentions either oracle or google in it.

1. It is possible in facebook and twitter. Is it doable in linkedin-j as well? I could not find apis other then search people, job and companies.
2. If yes please guide which api to use? site does not seems to have relevant docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found from documentation that linkedIn does not allow all that. It only can pull information specific to the authenticated user.